# How to get a div's content from the current page and Google it?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I was thinking about using jQuery, but I am very inexperienced when it comes to Chrome Extensions and JavaScript. I need to get a div off of a page (with the id, it's static, but the content is dynamic) when the user clicks the button. I'm having trouble grabbing the contents from the current page, and was wondering if anyone could either give me some tips or direct me to a relevant answer/tutorial.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want to do is submit the contents of the div as a query to Google, a simple one liner will do, no jQuery needed.

```
window.location = 'http://www.google.com/search?q='+encodeuricomponent(document.getElementById('theid').innerHTML);
```

Comment: I feel really dumb here, but where should I put that?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the ID, you can use jQuerys id-Selector: http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/
Once you found the div, you can get its text using this method http://api.jquery.com/text/

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so to do what you want you need to do three things. First is learn how to use [`content scripts`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) to inject your code into a given tab. Second would be getting the info you want from the tab, and last would be searching with the string you got in step 2. An example of all of these is as follows. For this code I am going to be using `domain.com` as the site where you want to get the info from.

**manifest.json**

```
"background": {
  "scripts": ["background.js"]
},
"permissions": [
  "tabs","*://www.domain.com/*"
],
"content_scripts": [{
  "matches": ["*://www.domain.com/*"],
  "js": ["jquery.js","getText.js"]
}]
```

**getText.js**

```
$('#buttonID').click(function(){
  // I am assuming that the contents are directly what you want to search with 
  var text = $('#divID').text();
  // At this point you could simply use window.location to search in this tab
  // but in the case you would rather open a new tab to search in
  // I will show you that as an example
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({method:'searchText',text:text});
});
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message,sender,sendResponse){
  if(message.method == 'searchText'){
    var url = "http://www.google.com/search?q="+encodeuricomponent(message.text);
    chrome.tabs.create({url:url});
  } 
});
```

This code will inject a `content script` into the desired page, grab the text out of the desired div when the button is clicked, send that text to the background page, and then open a new tab with that text as a search parameter. I kinda wrote this off the cuff, so sorry for any syntax errors.
  Also, jQuery is not needed as you can do this with pure javascript, but I showed you how to do it with it in case you needed it for something else.

Comment: Wow. I didn't mean for you to write practically the whole thing for me, but thanks! That must have been a lot of work. I will test this and get back to you.